# Find the best path using Greedy approach and max heap for ship

Tags: typescript, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm currently working on developing a game and I'm facing a programming challenge related to finding the fastest and safest path for a boat to travel from a starting point to a destination point on an island.
I'd greatly appreciate any assistance with this.
Here are the key parameters I'm dealing with:

the boat :

```
interface Boat {
  fuel: number;      // the fuel of my boat (at the begining )
  departure: string;     // starting island
  arrival: string;       // Island I want to reach
}
```

then, there is routes (which is the possible path (the graph)

`interface { routes: Record<string, { island: string; travelTime: number }[]> }`

The routes object represents the links between islands and the time needed to reach them (costed adjacency list) .
For instance :

```
routes: {
  Island1: [
      { island: "Island2", travelTime: 3 },
      { island: "Island3", travelTime: 2 },
    ]
```

travelTime represents the time and fuel required to reach the point.
Moreover, the only way to gain fuel is to stay in the same place.
For instance,  if I start with 4 days of fuel, travel to Island3, and stay there for 1 day, my current fuel becomes 4 - 2 + 1 = 3.

Additionally, there is also pirates :

```
interface {  pirates { island: string; day: number }[];   }
```

The pirates property indicates the whereabouts of pirates and the day they are present on a specific island. For instance:

for example :

```
pirates : [ island: "Island2", day : 3] // pirates on island2 at day 3
```

I need to account for the fact that each day spent with pirates reduces the success of the mission by a certain percentage (e.g., 10%).
It is allowed to backtrack to the previous island to avoid pirates.

And the last parameters is countdown, which indicates the limite time for the ship to reach the destination:

```
type Countdown : number
```

Here some example :

```
const boat: Boat = {
  fuel: 6,
  departure: "Island1",
  arrival: "Island3",
};

const routesData: Routes = {
  routes: {
    Island1: [
      { island: "Island2", travelTime: 6 },
    ],
    Island2: [
      { island: "Island3", travelTime: 1 },
      { island: "Island4", travelTime: 2 },
    ],
    Island3: [
      { island: "Island4", travelTime: 3 },
    ],
  },
};
const coundown : Countdown = 8;

const pirates: Pirate[] = [
  { island: "Island3", day: 6 },
  { island: "Island3", day: 7 },
  { island: "Island3", day: 8 },

];
```

in this example, the safest and fastest path is Island1 -> Island2 (stay) -> Island3 with a probability of 90%.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance to find an algorithm which can help me to solve this problem.

I try to check for the Dijkstra algorithm, Bellman–Ford algorithm and also And also yen's algorithm but I could not find something suit for this problem...

Comment: Thank you again @ravenspoint for your questions autonomy is kinda the fuel of the boat, you can be at 0 but you want down lower.
Staying one day in a island make you gain one point of autonomy : if I start with 4 days of autonomy, travel to Island3, and stay there for 1 day, my current autonomy becomes 4 - 2 + 1.

Comment: I just read it that greedy approach and max heep can make it faster, so I just delete everything to make it (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimize-refills-to-reach-end-of-path/amp/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I try to check for the Dijkstra algorithm, Bellman–Ford algorithm and also And also yen's algorithm but I could not find something suit for this problem."  What does 'try to check' mean?  Have you implemented these algorithms, or used a graph theory library that offers them?  You realise, I hope, that you need to use all three in the combination I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> It is allowed to backtrack to the previous island to avoid pirates.

Just noticed this new specification!  That makes things a lot simpler.

Here is my suggested algorithm:

```
    - Apply Dijkstra to find shortest sailing time path
    - Dodge pirates by staying on an island when present on next island 
    - IF no pirate dodging needed
         - Output Dijkstra path
         - STOP
    - Set bestPath to Dijkstra path, include dodging
    - LOOP over alternative paths ordered shortest first ( Yen's algorithm )
       - Ignore 1st path from Yen ( it has already be checked )
       - Dodge pirates by staying on an island when present on next island 
       - IF alternative path ( with any pirate dodging ) shorter than bestpath
           - Set bestPath to alternative path including any dodging
        - IF no pirate dodging needed
           - Output bestPath
           - STOP
        - ENDLOOP over alternative paths
    - Output bestPath
```

Applied to your example problem, this find the path:

```
isle1 at time 0
isle2 at time 6
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle2
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle2
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle2
isle3 at time 9
```

Applied to the example

void generateExample2()
{
addAdjacentIslands("isle1", "isle2", 6);
addAdjacentIslands("isle1", "isle3", 1);
addAdjacentIslands("isle2", "isle4", 2);
addAdjacentIslands("isle3", "isle4", 3);

```
addPirate("isle3", 1);
addPirate("isle3", 2);
addPirate("isle3", 3);
addPirate("isle3", 4);
addPirate("isle3", 5);

setBoat("isle1", "isle4");
```

}

the algorithm finds the best alternative, even though it requires more sailing

```
isle1 at time 0
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle1 at time 1
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle1 at time 2
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle1 at time 3
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle1 at time 4
Pirates on isle3 staying on isle1 at time 5
isle3 at time 6
isle4 at time 9
Check alternative path
isle1 at time 0
isle2 at time 6
isle4 at time 8
better path: more sailing less pirates

at time 0 isle1
sailing sailing sailing sailing sailing sailing
at time 6 arrive isle2
sailing sailing
at time 8 arrive isle4
```

The output is from a C++ application ( my typescript is inadequate ) using the PathFinder graph theory library.  If you are interested, the complete application code is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PirateIslands

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer !
I have never heard about Yen's algorithm sounds great ! thank you
however, I can still go to place with pirate ( juste reduce the probability to arrive each time you encounter pirate) yen's algorithm works with that ?

Btw, in this problem we can also go back to island if it's safer also

Comment: My suggested algorithm avoids the chance of meeting pirates.  Nasty people and I think they might well have body odor.  Why take the risk?

Comment: In some cases you can still reach the goal even if there is pirate (for example : if there is pirate and the goal place until the last day) I still wanted to display a path (but with probability reduce by n percent)

Comment: with your explication I can now find a way to solve this problem, however I still don’t figure it out how to combine the graph after the 2 and yen’s algorithm to find the best graph

Comment: I change the description of the problem to make it more clear, fuel station is not useful, sorry for unclear problem

Comment: OK, I have removed the fuel optimization from my answer.

Comment: Have you tried implementing  this algorithm?  How did you get on?  What problem(s) did you have?

Comment: Updated algorithm to use backtracking to dodge pirates and to search alternative paths for the best one considering sailing times AND time spent avoiding pirates

Comment: Moved application into its own github repo https://github.com/JamesBremner/PirateIslands

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the algorithm ! ( Sorry I loose my other account, can't comment);
I gonna try to change the implementation into typescript, however, I didn't see countdown (the maximum time to reach the point)
also, this line :

```
 Dodge pirates by staying on an island when present on next island
```

Might be a problem with countdown (ie : if there is pirates at the end, there is no chance to reach the destination)

implemented, for that, I should only remove from allPath the which take more time than countdown ?
**Note** : I made a mistake If we stay 1 day in the same island refuel = we get back the autonomy !

Thank you again

I managed to solve the problem but the program is really slow since I try all the possibility :

```
interface Boat {
  fuel: number;
  departure: string;
  arrival: string;
}

interface Route {
  island: string;
  travelTime: number;
}

interface Routes {
  routes: Record<string, Route[]>;
}

interface Pirate {
  island: string;
  day: number;
}

type Countdown = number;

function findSafestPath(
  boat: Boat,
  routesData: Routes,
  pirates: Pirate[],
  countdown: Countdown
): { path: string[]; safety: number } {
  const { fuel, departure, arrival } = boat;
  const { routes } = routesData;

  const queue: {
    island: string;
    fuelLeft: number;
    path: string[];
    safety: number;
    timeSpent: number;
  }[] = [];

  const visited: Record<string, number> = {};

  queue.push({
    island: departure,
    fuelLeft: fuel,
    path: [departure],
    safety: 100,
    timeSpent: 0,
  });

  let safestPath: string[] = [];
  let maxSafety = 0;

  while (queue.length > 0) {
    const { island, fuelLeft, path, safety, timeSpent } = queue.shift()!;
    if (island === arrival) {
      if (safety > maxSafety || safety === 100) {
        maxSafety = safety;
        safestPath = path.slice();
        
      }
      continue;
    }
    if (timeSpent <= countdown) {
      visited[island] = safety;
    
    for (const route of routes[island] || []) {
      const { island: nextIsland, travelTime } = route;
      const remainingFuel = fuelLeft - travelTime;
      const nextTimeSpent = timeSpent + travelTime;
      const nextSafety = getSafety(safety, pirates, nextIsland, nextTimeSpent);
      const currentSafety = getSafety(safety, pirates, island, timeSpent + 1);
      
      if (fuelLeft === 0 || nextSafety < currentSafety  ) {
        queue.push({
          island,
          fuelLeft: fuel,
          path: path.concat(island),
          safety: currentSafety,
          timeSpent: timeSpent + 1
        });
      }
      if (remainingFuel >= 0 && nextTimeSpent <= countdown) {
        queue.push({
          island: nextIsland,
          fuelLeft: remainingFuel,
          path: path.concat(nextIsland),
          safety: nextSafety,
          timeSpent: nextTimeSpent
        });
      }
    }
  }
  }
  return { path: safestPath, safety: maxSafety };
}

function getSafety(safety: number, pirates: Pirate[], island: string, currentDay: Countdown): number {
  for (const pirate of pirates) {
    if (pirate.island === island && pirate.day === currentDay) {
      safety -= 10; // Reduce safety by 10% for each day with pirates
    }
  }
  return safety;
}
```

Here my algorithm base on your in typescript but it didn't work ...

```
import { Edge, Graph, Path, alg } from 'graphlib'
import {ksp, IPath}  from './yens';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

type Dijkstra = {
    [node: string]: Path;
}

type Pirate = {
    day : number;
    planet :string
}

type Route = {
    source : string,
    destination : string,
    travelTime : number,
}

type SafePath = {
  path: Route[];
  danger: number;
}

const insert = <T>(arr : T[], index : number, newItem : T[] ) : T[ ]=> [
  ...arr.slice(0, index),
  ...newItem,
  ...arr.slice(index)
]

// build a new edge object
const getNewRoute  = (source : string,  destination : string , travelTime : number) : Route => ({
    source,
    destination,
    travelTime  
})

const pathToRoute = (path : IPath) => 
  path.edges.map(({fromNode, toNode, weight })=>  getNewRoute(fromNode,toNode, weight))

const routeToPath = (routes : Route[]) : IPath => ({
edges : routes.map(({source, destination, travelTime })=>  ({
  fromNode : source , toNode : destination, weight :travelTime})),
totalCost : routes.reduce((cost, route) => cost += route.travelTime, 0 )
})
const getPathFromDijkstra = (dijkstra : Dijkstra, source : string, target : string, weightFn :  (e: Edge) => number) => {
    // check if there is a valid path
    if (dijkstra[target].distance === Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
        return null;
    }

    const edges : Route[] = [];
    let currentNode = target;
    let weightValue : number = 0;
    while (currentNode !== source) {
        let previousNode = dijkstra[currentNode].predecessor;

        // extract weight from edge, using weightFunc if supplied, or the default way
      
        weightValue = weightFn({ v: previousNode, w: currentNode });
        let edge = getNewRoute(previousNode, currentNode, weightValue);
        edges.push(edge);
        currentNode = previousNode;
    }

    return  edges.reverse();
}

const getDijkstra = (graph : Graph, source : string, destination : string) => {
    const weightFn = (e : Edge) : number => graph.edge(e)

    const dijkstra = alg.dijkstra(graph, source, weightFn);
    return getPathFromDijkstra(dijkstra, source, destination, weightFn);
}


const hasBountyHunters = (bountyHunters : Pirate[], planet : string, day : number) : number => 
    Number(bountyHunters.some((bountyHunter) => bountyHunter.planet === planet && bountyHunter.day === day ))

const saferPath = (bountyHunters : Pirate[], routes : Route[], startingDay : number) => {
  let travel = startingDay;
  let danger = 0;
  routes.forEach((route) => {
    travel += route.travelTime;
    if(hasBountyHunters(bountyHunters, route.source, travel)){
      danger += 1;
    } 
})
  return danger;
}    

const findAlternativePath = (graph : Graph, bountyHunters : Pirate[], source : string, destination : string, countdown : number, currentTime : number, danger : number) =>{

  const paths = ksp(graph, source, destination, 200).filter(({totalCost}) => totalCost < countdown);
  paths.splice(0, 1)
  let bestPath : IPath = paths[0];
  paths.some((path) =>  {
   const routes = pathToRoute(path);
    if(saferPath(bountyHunters, routes, currentTime) <= danger){
      bestPath = path;
      return true
    }
  });
  return pathToRoute(bestPath);
}   

const fastestPath = (routes : Route[], bountyHunters : Pirate[], fuel : number, countdown : number) : SafePath | undefined => {
    let time = 0;
    const safestPath : Route[] = [];
    let autonomy = fuel;
    let bountyHuntersEncounter = 0;
    const { destination } = routes.at(-1) ?? {}
    for (let i = 0; safestPath.at(-1)?.destination !== destination && time <= countdown; ) {
        const route = routes.at(i);
        if(route == null) break;

        const newTime = route.travelTime + time;
        const newFuel = autonomy - route.travelTime;
        const isIdle = route.source === route.destination;

       if((autonomy - route.travelTime) >= 0 && (newTime <= countdown)) {
          const isNotSafe = hasBountyHunters(bountyHunters, route.destination, newTime);
          bountyHuntersEncounter += isNotSafe;
            time = newTime;
            autonomy = newFuel;
            safestPath.push(route)
            i++;
        }
        else if(isIdle || autonomy < fuel ) {
          const isStaySafe = hasBountyHunters(bountyHunters, route.source, time+1);
          const idle =  getNewRoute(route.source, route.source, 1);
          bountyHuntersEncounter += isStaySafe;
          time++;
          safestPath.push(idle);
          autonomy = fuel;
          if(isIdle) i++
        }
        else break;
    }
    return safestPath.at(-1)?.destination === destination  ? { path : safestPath, danger : bountyHuntersEncounter} : undefined
}

const avoidBountyHunters = (routes : Graph, routePath : SafePath, bountyHunter : Pirate[], fuel : number, countdown : number ) : SafePath | undefined => {
  let day = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < routePath.path.length; index++) {
    const route = routePath.path[index];
    day += route.travelTime;
    if(hasBountyHunters(bountyHunter, route.destination, day)){
      let newRoutes :Route[] ;
      const routeUpdate = [...routePath.path];
      let alternative : Route[]
      if(route.source === route.destination && index > 1){
        const elaspsedTime = day -1 - routePath.path[index-2].travelTime;
        newRoutes = findAlternativePath(routes, bountyHunter, routePath.path[index-2].source,  routePath.path.at(-1).destination, countdown, elaspsedTime, routePath.danger);
        console.log(routeUpdate)

        routeUpdate.splice(index-2, Infinity);
        alternative =  [...routeUpdate, ...newRoutes]
      }
      else { 
        newRoutes = findAlternativePath(routes, bountyHunter, route.source, route.destination, countdown, day, routePath.danger);
        routeUpdate.splice(index, 1)
        alternative = insert(routeUpdate, day, newRoutes);

      }
      const newPath = fastestPath(alternative, bountyHunter, fuel, countdown);

      if(newPath == null ){ return routePath }
      else if(_.isEqual(newPath.path, routePath.path)){

        return newPath;
      }
      else { 
       return avoidBountyHunters(routes, newPath, bountyHunter, fuel, countdown)}
    }
  }
  return routePath;
}
```

Comment: "program is really slow since I try all the possibility"  Of course.  That is why my answer uses Dijkstra and Yen algorithms to obtain the optimum paths directly.  On your example problem the optimum path is returned instantly.

Comment: "I didn't see countdown"  This is trivial to implement.  If the optimum path is too long for the countdown, print a failure message.  There is no point in continuing because all other paths will be longer than the optimum _and_ the countdown

Comment: " I loose my other account"  If you cannot restore your account, we will be unable to communicate properly here.  Two options: 1: You can communicate with me using github issues on https://github.com/JamesBremner/PirateIslands/issues 2:  Ask the question again with your new account and link back to this question

Comment: I have added the refueling feature.  If the boat does not carry enough fuel to reach the next island, it remains at one island until it does.

Comment: Wow thank you again ! I will convert it in typescript, I managed to write yen algorithm in TS since it does not really exist ! that's a good start